# Сохранение тяжелых данных при изменении ориентации экрана

Tags: android

Пытаюсь разобраться с тем, как правильно сохранять данные. Но чувствую, что буксую ...

Допустим, есть Activity, для которой в onCreate создается и присваивается ListView кастомный адаптер, причем:

1. Адаптер содержит список тяжелых объектов (например, картинок)
2. Эти картинки закачиваются из сети (в отдельном потоке, который создается в момент создания адаптера) и нужны только в рамках текущей сессии работы с приложением (т.е. постоянно их хранить не требуется).

Соответственно при изменении ориентации экрана, нужно как-то сохранять полученные данные, чтобы продолжать с ними работать. Я вижу следующие варианты:

1. Сохранять адаптер в RetainedFragment.
2. Использовать onSaveInstanceState() для сохранения адаптера. При этом для адаптера нужно реализовать интерфейс Parcelable.
3. Сохранять данные в SQLite, и при смене ориентации – брать их оттуда. Далее, по истечении времени, уничтожать данные. Адаптер же создавать заново.
4. Использовать onRetainNonConfigurationInstance для адаптера.

Как правильно поступить? Куда смотреть?

Comment: Можно сделать сохранение картинок в кэш, а после завершения программы пусть работает сервис и очищает их и потом самоубивается. Либо при новом включении приложения очистка кэша

Comment: Как решили вопрос? Может, просто запретить повторный вызов onCreate?

Comment: В том приложении использовал RetainedFragment. Но в последующих начал кэшировать.

Answer (score 1):

Добавить кэширования картинок с сохранением на диск. Лучше поискать готовые библиотеки

Для загрузки изображений - можно использовать библиотеку Picasso. Которая умеет кэшировать изобаржения. К тому же хорошо обрабатывает разъединение/подключение к интернету

Comment: Спасибо! В принципе я использую [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) он умеет кэшировать. Просто есть соблазн сохранить адаптер целиком со всем его содержимым в `RetainedFragment` и спокойно жить дальше.

Comment: @AndreyEKB всегда и в любой непонятной ситуации так делаю)

Answer (score -1):

Первый вариант.
Заодно потом будет проще если решите сделать отличия в дизайне приложения при альбомной и ландшафтной ориентации

Второй вариант - будем памяти затратной
Третий вариант - плохая идея изначально, так как вам придется работать с энергонезависимой памятью - а это и долго и эхнергозатратно
Четвертый вариант - не знаю